# Can't get flexbox columns to be equal height

Tags: css, flexbox

I can't seem to figure out how to get both columns to be the same height. I've copied code from several examples and it's not producing the same results.

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cta">
        <a>Link</a>
    </div>
</div>


.flex-container {
    display: flex;  
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-container div {
    display:flex;
}
.flex-container .list {
    width: 70%;
    background:#cccccc;
}
.flex-container .cta {
    width: 30%;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/aro_007/pen/VrpGLV

Comment: When you set the container to `align-items: center` that overrides the default `align-items: stretch`, which is the source of equal height columns in flexbox. See the duplicate for more details and a workaround.